# informatica : why i am getting error while using iif function?

Tags: etl, decode, informatica-powercenter, iif-function

I have column 'GENDER' where values 'M or 'F' comes in , anyother value coming, i want to populate as 'UNK' using IIF in expression tranf informatica. i am getting error

> operand cannot be converted to number

using below expression

```
iif(GENDER='M' OR 'F','TRUE','UNK')
```

Comment: don't know anything about informatica, but are you sure this is correct syntax: `GENDER='M' OR 'F'` since I've never seen anything like that anywhere

Comment: im no sure about the syntax, i just want to use iif for populating gender other than m or f as UNK...

Comment: Well then just by guessing I would at least try something like `iif(GENDER='M' OR GENDER='F','TRUE','UNK')`  Although I don't understand why you want to show either "true" or "unk" in the field...

Comment: the target should populate gender as m or f anything other than this should populagte as UNK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code

```
iif(GENDER='M' OR GENDER='F',GENDER,'UNK')
```

if its M or F then use original column else populate UNK.